# Múltiples botones que lancen el mismo modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buen día colegas, soy principiante y necesito su ayuda.

Tengo un botón que lanza un modal para editar un registro en una tabla. El problema que tengo es que al generar el ciclo para visualizar los "n" registros de la tabla solo funciona el primer botón, es decir, sólo el primer botón lanza el modal, los demás quedan estáticos. Agradeceré su orientación.

Comparto el ejemplo del código:

```js
<script>
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById("pop");

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById("popup-button");

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
  btn.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

```css
.edit {
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(120,100,93);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button class="edit" id="popup-button"><img src="img/edit.png"/></button>

<div class="popup" id="pop">
 <div class="popup-content ">
  ...contenido
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cómo vas a generar las filas para cada registro de la tabla, debes tener en cuentas dos cosas:

1. Crear cada boton con una clase, para asociar el evento a esa clase, con id no funciona, puesto que hay muchos botones.
2. Asociar el envento a los botones utilizando delegación de eventos. Aquí te anexo un script de guía para tu proyecto.

```js
function delegate(el, evt, sel, handler) {
    el.addEventListener(evt, function(event) {
        var t = event.target;
        while (t && t !== this) {
            if (t.matches(sel)) {
                handler.call(t, event);
            }
            t = t.parentNode;
        }
    });
}

delegate(document, "click", ".some_elem", function(event) {
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true));
    this.style.border = "2px dashed orange";
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="some_elem">
    <span>
      CLICK ME
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Saludos,

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu ejemplo me ha ayudado a comprender cómo debo hacerlo.